# Implicit vs explicit solutions and slope fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I thought implicit solutions could also be a family of solutions, like x^2 + y^2 = C.  In that case, y is separable from x, so it would seem to be explicit from the answers [written here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/difference-between-implicit-and-explicit-solutions) and [Paul](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Definitions.aspx).  However, in the Nagle Diff Eq book, it often uses the language 'implicit solutions' when talking about drawing multiple solutions on a slope field plot.

Also in Nagle, implicit solutions are defined as "a solution on the Interval I if it defines one or more explicit solutions", and an explicit solution is basically one solution to a differential equation that satisfies the equation for all x on the interval I.

So is x^2 + y^2 = C an implicit or explicit solution?

Update: Nagle's exact definitions in the book are these:

Explicit Solution: A function f(x) that when substituted for y in F(x, y, dy/dx, ... d^ny/dx^n) = 0 satisfies the equation for all x in the interval I is called an explicit solution to the equation on I.

Implicit Solution: A relation G(x,y) = 0 is said to be an implicit solution to F(x, y, dy/dx, ... d^ny/dx^n) = 0 on the interval I if it defines one or more explicit solutions on I.

Comment: It is implicit, as it leads to multiple solutions over the same interval due to the square root

Comment: According to one definition, but not the other.  Plus the C would mean it has multiple solutions regardless of the square root.  The crux of the question is still: which definition is correct?

Comment: The thing I mean to say is that for a given value of C, there are still multiple values of $y$ for every $x$ because of the square root. What Nagle says doesn't disagree with the other definitions as it is very common for an implicitly defined function to have multiple explicit solutions (if they can even be found explicitly).

Comment: My understanding is that Nagle's definition is implicit solutions are a family of solutions, but the other definition largely found on the web says implicit solutions are those that can separate independent/dependent variables on two sides of the equation.  So the internet definition would say x^2 + y^2 = C is explicit, while Nagle would say it's implicit.

Comment: By the way do you have a link to the text wherein Nagle defines the term implicit or at least uses it? The reason I ask is because you can graph families of solutions for both explicit formulas and implicit ones, as the solution is typically decided by the initial conditions. I suppose it would be helpful to see the context

Comment: No, unfortunately the book is not free.  It is available from Pearson for a hefty price.  I will update the question with exact quotes of his definitions though.